# C# Forms - How do I draw outside of Form_Paint method?

Tags: .net, forms, paint, draw

I have made a Windows Forms Application, and have a Paint event:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Font title = new Font("Calibari", 40);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World!", title, new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Point(200, 200));
    }
```

And I also have a timer, that ticks each 5 milliseconds, and it does this.Refresh() every tick (in case I'll draw strings that contain variables, and then I'll have to update them).

But can I draw strings outside of the Paint event?

For example, paint a string when the user clicks a button. How do I do such thing?

Comment: Yes you can, but they will disappear as soon as the form is invalidated or refreshed. Any thing that you need to persist to your form will need to be in the Paint Event

Comment: But that's a problem... If for example, I want to display a string after a button is pressed, how can I do such thing in the Paint event?

Comment: I would build a class of the information that you are trying to use create a list then iterate through it in your paint event. I will try to come up with a quick example.  I also have used hidden labels in the past and just drawn their information on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out my Comment, this is the first way that I suggested creating a class to store your information in. This will work if the number of strings are dynamic. otherwise the second option is easier.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<MyStringInformation> myTextInfo = new List<MyStringInformation>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyStringInformation info = new MyStringInformation();
        info.myFont = new Font("Calibari", 40);
        info.myText = "Hello World";
        info.myLocation = new Point(200, 200);
        info.myColor = Color.Blue;
        myTextInfo.Add(info);
        Refresh();

    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        foreach (var item in myTextInfo)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.myText, item.myFont, new SolidBrush(item.myColor), item.myLocation);
        }
    }
}

public class MyStringInformation
{
    public Font myFont { get; set; }
    public string myText { get; set;}
    public Point myLocation { get; set;}
    public Color myColor { get; set;}
}
```

Or just to be simple have a label on your form, it can be hidden or not even a part of the Forms Control Collection set its properties then extract the information in the paint event.  As an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Label myTitle = new Label();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTitle.Font = new Font("Calibari", 40);
        myTitle.Text = "Hello World";
        myTitle.Location = new Point(200, 200);
        myTitle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        Refresh();

    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(myTitle.Text, myTitle.Font, new SolidBrush(myTitle.ForeColor), myTitle.Location);
     }
}
```

Comment: Haven't thought of it. I'm absolutely going to use it. Thank you very much!